# Cannot display progress bar while page loading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working in admin backend application. My application uses soap api response to display contents so the process takes too much time for loading.

So i planned to show progress bar untill page.. I have searched a lot and got a perfect answer by this link [Progress bar example demo site](https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/post/accurate-page-progress-bar)

By the reference of this site. i have added below html code inside `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="preloader-wrap" > 
  <div class="percentage" id="precent">100%</div>
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="trackbar">
      <div class="loadbar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="glow" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And added my css code

```
.loadbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg, 
    #008737, 
    #008737 10px, 
    #69AF23 10px,
    #69AF23 20px
  ); /* Stripes Background Gradient */

  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px #008737; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: flicker 5s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.glow {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px 10px #008737;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  animation: animation 5s infinite;
}
```

And my js is

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

var width = 100,
perfData = window.performance.timing, 
EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart), 
time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100; 


// Percentage Increment Animation
var PercentageID = $("#precent"),
    start = 0,
    end = 100,
    durataion = time;
    animateValue(PercentageID, start, end, durataion);

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {

    var range = end - start,
      current = start,
      increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
      stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
      obj = $(id);

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        $(obj).text(current + "%");
      //obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
// Loadbar Animation
$(".loadbar").animate({
  width: width + "%"
}, time);

// Loadbar Glow Animation
$(".glow").animate({
  width: width + "%"
}, time);
});
```

Im not getting exact output and my page displayed like below and i want to display progress bar of page loading 0 to 100% untill page loads after page loaded i want to hide it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHqkD.png)

The progress bar is appended to my page. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: the combination of `height:100%; position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;` rules on the .loadbar element will cause it to cover the whole page, if there is nothing else to constrain it. If you look at the actual CodePen on that tutorial page (https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/MwppEB to run it separately) you'll see there's actually quite a lot more CSS you need. The tutorial is perhaps a little bit unclear on that.